# Blazor Timer One Instance Per User Session

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side app and I am using a timer to check for new messages for the user and display a message when new message arrives. Here are my codes:

```
private string hasMsg { get; set; }
private System.Threading.Timer _timer;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        if (_timer == null)
        {
            _timer = new System.Threading.Timer((_) =>
            {
                InvokeAsync(async () =>
                {
                    hasMsg = await GetValue();
                    StateHasChanged();
                });
            }, null, 0, 30000);//every 30 seconds
        }
    }
}
```

The GetValue() function simply calls an API.

This works well initially. However, whenever I refresh the browser, a new timer instance will be instantiated and the API will be called twice every 30 seconds. I guess this makes sense as when browser is refreshed, the entire page is re-rendered. So how do I ensure either the previous timer is disposed or not to start a new timer instance and re-used the one already running?

Keep in mind I need to have each user of the application to have his own timer. The API call receives user-specific information. Thanks!

Comment: You already have an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062755/

Comment: And why do you Invoke() the GetValue() ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not sure, but maybe you can't call `StateHasChanged` if it isn't inside `InvokeAsync`?

Comment: Yes, you should Invoke the StateHasChanged(). But not the potentially slow GetValue().  See the link.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop the timer when the page refreshes you should do the following:

You need to call `_timer.Dispose` to stop the timer.

The place for that would be in the `Dispose` method from `IDisposable`.

So the component that use the timer should implement `IDisposable` and in the overridden `Dispose` method, call `_time.Dipose()`.