# C# Blazor: Countdown Timer

Tags: c#, blazor, system.timers.timer

I'm new to C# and trying to create a simple countdown timer using `System.Timer.Timers`. It didn't work as expected and I searched the internet for a solution but it didn't really fix my problem. What I want is when the user clicks the start button, it begins and displays the countdown. But although the timer kinda worked, it didn't continuously display the timer when I clicked the button once, instead, I need to click the start button many times to see the countdown number or the timer display will not change. Here's the code.

```
@page "/"

<h1>Timer</h1>

<p>@counter</p>
<button @onclick="StartTimer">Start</button>


@code {
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    private int counter = 60;
    public void StartTimer()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += CountDownTimer;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void CountDownTimer(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            counter -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the Dispose() logic. A Timer is IDisposable.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Call `StateHasChanged()` when updating the counter so that the UI elements are updated.

Because your callback will run on a separate thread you will need to use InvokeAsync to call StateHasChanged().

```
public void CountDownTimer(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        counter -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to Dispose() the Timer. [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062755/60761)

Comment: InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) doesn't works, you shoud use 
 InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged);

Comment: @Payedmaunt do you have more information on your test scenario? The overload of InvokeAction used here takes an Action delegate, which has a signature of `void ()` this matches the signature for `StateHasChanges` as well as the lambda you are passing. As it stands `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` works, so there might be something you have different in your test case.

Comment: InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) definitely works, its the same as doing InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged) since StateHasChanged has no parameters