# Blazor throwing exception when client navigates away from webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm having a weird issue. I have a Blazor server-side webpage with a built in timer that runs every second to force an update of the webpage. When the client closes the browser window or navigates away from the webpage, I get these exception errors being thrown every second:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

I'm assuming these errors are being caused as the timer is still active but the client has disconnected but not sure. Am I missing some code detect the client navigating away and to kill the instance of the webpage on the server side?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your web page should implement `IDisposable` and dispose/unsubscribe from the timer.

Comment: @BrianParker, your comment looks like the right answer. What about to write an answer with this?

Comment: Disposing a Timer in Blazor has come up before. [Here is a code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062755/60761).