# Blazor-Server side UI Updating does not work or only partially

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I have the following issue:

I have a frontend where certain Values are set by the Backend. The Values are saved in Lists and these List-Elements should be displayed at the frontend.

This works if at first load, at Refreshing the page manually etc... but not when using StateHasChanged() or ShouldRender()

While searching I found this article:
[Blazor Timer call async API task to update UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060065/blazor-timer-call-async-api-task-to-update-ui)

So I was adding the Timer, and the Timer is indeed refreshing but only for like 30 seconds, afterwards it won't be refreshed anymore.

```
 <ul>
        @Time
 </ul>
```

````
System.Threading.Timer timer;
private string Time { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _servers = DataCollection.srv;
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((_) =>
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }, null, 0, 1000);
    base.OnInitialized();```
````

While the timer is refreshing all other elements will be refreshed too. But Refreshing the timer stops randomly, sometimes after 60s, sometimes after 2s. Clicking a button (which triggers a refresh by default) or anything won't start it again.

My question is: Why does it only work for a random amount of time?

Thanks for your time and sorry if this might be trivial

Comment: Try to assign to timer variable instead of introducing a new timer variable in method local scope using ' var timer = ........ "

Comment: As you've said that this is Blazor Server, why aren't you using events in the backend that are raised when something changes.  The front end registers with these events and updates as needed.  If you want some example code I will happy post you some in an answer.

Comment: Hi, I tried it event based first but somehow the StateHasChanged didn't trigger for me, if you can provide an example I'm always happy to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ul>
        @Time
        <button onclick="@Collect">Collect</button>
 </ul>

@code {
    System.Threading.Timer timer;
    private string Time { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {       
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((_) =>
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }, null, 0, 1000);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    void Collect()
    {
        GC.Collect();            
    }
 }
```

Try above code on https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet. Since you are assigning Timer to a local variable in method scope , it is eventually garbage collected and your timer won't trigger anymore. You can simulate same using above example where I have introduced a button to trigger Garbage collection explicitly.
Change in example to assign to timer variable instead of local var timer variable and try to trigger Garbage collection again and timer won't stop this time.

Comment: Yes, but simple answer would be `var timer` creates a separate local variable, even with the same name than a global one. Therefore, just remove `var`. I am not sure that giving the example that local variables are eventually removed from memory is necessary.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Here's my test page based on your code.  It uses `Task.Delay` to emulate your
`_servers = DataCollection.srv;`.  It doesn't freeze after 30-60 seconds.

That suggests there's a problem in `_servers = DataCollection.srv;`.  Change out this line for the `await Task./Delay(100)` in your code and verify were the problem is.

```
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="p-2">
    @this.Time
</div>

@code {

    System.Threading.Timer? timer;

    private string Time { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // emulate a data get
        await Task.Delay(100);
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((_) =>
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }, null, 0, 1000);
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Also why are you calling `base.OnInitialized();` from `OnInitializedAsync()`?

It's already been run: `OnInitialized()` is called by `ComponentBase` before `OnInitializedAsync()`.