# What is the best way to use PeriodicTimer for refresh component in blazor server

Tags: timer, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a component that needs to display fresh data every 1 minute.

I tried the new timer (Periodic Timer) and it works fine.

Now, my questions are,

**Where is the best place to put the while loop?**

**Is something else required for a proper dispose of the PeriodicTimer?**

```
public partial class Index:IDisposable
{
    private readonly PeriodicTimer _periodicTimer = new(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Service.Init();
        while (await _periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {
            await Service.GetViewModels();
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
           _periodicTimer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Blazor do you use?  I tried to mock this up with Task.Delay() but it won't even start (6.0). I think i did see it work in earlier versions.

Comment: @HenkHolterman project is `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: I'll have to try again later then. Maybe Task.Delay() has changed.

Comment: Some criticism: You keep OnInitialized running , blocking parameters. And it just looks wrong. The Dispose() is overdone, you don't need SuppressFinalize or bool disposing.

Comment: I would go for Systems.Threading.Timer, with an async void event.

Comment: See this anser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062755/60761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I put the code in `Index`, i.e. the statup page, it never completes loading.

If I put the code in another page, it looks like it running fine but it isn't.

The problem is that `OnInitializedAsync` never completes.  It's always awaiting in the `while` loop. Therefore the rest of the initial component lifecycle doesn't complete either.

As a startup page, it gets locked in the initial server load.

To solve the problem you need to "fire and forget" the timer loop.

Here's a demo component that works, and how to use the "older" timer with an event handler (which I personally would stick with).

```cs
@page "/Test"
@implements IDisposable

<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="m-2">
    Message: @message
</div>
<div class="m-2">
   Timer Message: @timerMessage
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    @state
</div>
@code {
    private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    private readonly PeriodicTimer _periodicTimer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    private string message = "Starting";
    private string timerMessage = "Starting";
    private string state = "On Init Running";

    // This is broken code 
    //protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    //{
    //    while (await _periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
    //    {
    //        message = $"Updated at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
    //        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    //    }
    //}

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        RunTimer();
        state = "On Init complete";

        // Uses System.Timers.Timer
        timer.Elapsed += TimeElapsed;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;

    }

    private async void TimeElapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // emulate an async data get
        await Task.Delay(100);
        timerMessage = $"Updated at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    } 

    protected async void RunTimer()
    {
        while (await _periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {
            // emulate an async data get
            await Task.Delay(100);
            message = $"Updated at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _periodicTimer.Dispose();
            timer.Elapsed -= TimeElapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be a better answer with just one option. And without the disposing/SuppressFinalize stuff.

Comment: I tend to agree.  I did simplify `Dispose`.   I was trying to demonstrate the two options.  I'm not sure I like the `RunTimer` option anyway.  I haven't dug into the code, but I suspect PeriodicTimer is just another wrapper for `System.Threading.Timer`.

Comment: The component where I used the sample code was not the application Index(first page), actually, all my components with routing are named index. Indeed, I could use a simple timer to refresh my component ViewModel, but I found the PeriodicTIme as an easy read/write implementation. I end up using the while loop in the `OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)` when is firstRender. Till now I saw no problem in the production environment.